# gpxpy doesn't parse time attribute of track points

Tags: python, xml-parsing, gpx

i'm trying to parse gpx file made by "Mission Planner". For some reason the softwere generates the gpx file of one line, which look like that:

```
<gpx creator="Mission Planner 1.3.48 build 1.1.6330.31130 ArduPlane V3.7.1 (22b5c415)" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"><trk><trkseg><trkpt lat="31.7562743" lon="35.1812861"><ele>719.5</ele><time>2017-06-13T20:08:28+03:00</time><course>113.6</course><roll>-165.05</roll><pitch>1.74</pitch><mode /></trkpt><trkpt lat="31.7562703" lon="35.1812854"><ele>723.3</ele><time>2017-06-13T20:08:29+03:00</time><course>94.72</course><roll>-168.73</roll><pitch>8.55</pitch><mode /></trkpt><trkpt lat="31.7562648" lon="35.1812912"><ele>725.2</ele><time>2017-06-13T20:08:30+03:00</time><course>86.72</course><roll>-172.74</roll><pitch>4.67</pitch><mode /></trkpt> (...)
```

When i try to parse the gpx file with gpxpy (gpxpy-1.1.2), the track points have an empty time attributes, even though they do have have a  field in the gpx file:

```
In [76]: a = gpx.tracks[0]
         b = a.segments[0]
         c = b.points[1]
         d = [c.longitude, c.latitude, c.elevation, c.time]
         d

Out[76]: [35.1812854, 31.7562703, 723.3, None]
```

obviously, that kills all the speed / duration calculations.

ideas? suggestions?
+ if anyone knows a parser / script that can change the gpx file to be readable, that would be nice. i'v tried to write one of my own, but the \n i insert somehow fuck up the gpx file, the gpxpy cannot parse it at all.

thx ahead,
Forest.

Comment: The time attributes are not correct. In GPX files the dates and times should be in ISO 8601 format: 2017-01-01T20:05:01Z. [Docs](http://www.topografix.com/gpx_manual.asp#time)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Thx for the quick response. any idea how to extract the data using xml parsing functions, or somehow replace the timestamp format?

Answer (score 1):

The GPX time format you posted is not correct. Let's try it with a GPX file that has the correct time format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx creator="StravaGPX" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtensionv1.xsd" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1" xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3">
 <metadata>
  <time>2017-08-07T14:46:23Z</time>
 </metadata>
 <trk>
  <name>Ride</name>
  <type>1</type>
  <trkseg>
   <trkpt lat="33.6545510" lon="-117.8939470">
    <ele>0.0</ele>
    <time>2017-08-07T14:46:23Z</time>
    <extensions>
     <gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>
      <gpxtpx:atemp>20</gpxtpx:atemp>
     </gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>
    </extensions>
   </trkpt>
```

As mentioned, the python code when using gpxpy is:

```
trax = gpx.tracks[0]
seg = trax.segments[0]
pt = seg.points[1]
print(pt.time)
```

Output:

```
2017-08-07 14:46:23+00:00
```